# Regex in Ruby to match first and second space of strings

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I´m trying to get a regex to match first and second space and ":" from second column of strings like below in order to replace them with "|". I built the regex below but matches the opposite, since matches any word, not first and second space, nor ":". Maybe someone could give a hand with this.

```
(\S+\s*) (\S+\s*) (\S+\s*)  # My current regex
```

Strings are like these.

```
Usw 12:12 Desktop
Usw 1:2 Netbooks
Usw 1:345 Servers, mainframes and supercomputers
```

I´d like to convert these strings from above to this

```
Usw|12|12|Desktop
Usw|1|2|Netbooks
Usw|1|345|Servers, mainframes and supercomputers
```

Comment: `str.gsub(/\s(\d+):(\d+)\s/,'|\1|\2|')`

Comment: @SagarPandya the latter is the best answer here, I believe you should have it posted (as an answer.)

Comment: Thanks Sagar, shortest and simpler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the solution might be even simpler:

```
'Usw 12:12 Desktop'.split(/\s|:/, 4).join('|')
#⇒ "Usw|12|12|Desktop"
```

The above will fail if the first column has colons, but I am pretty sure this is not the case.

Comment: Excellent mudacobwa. Thanks so much

Comment: Nice use of `split`'s often-overlooked second argument. Perhaps `/\s+|:/` in case there are multiple spaces.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `gsub` here:

```
input = String.new("Usw 1:345 Servers, mainframes and supercomputers")
puts input.gsub(/(\S+)\s*(\d+):(\d+)\s*(.*)/, '\1|\2|\3|\4')

Usw|1|345|Servers, mainframes and supercomputers
```

### Demo

The basic idea here is that we capture the non space content before the first space, after the first space, and the remainder of the string after the second space.  Then we build the output string you want using those capture groups.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim, it works pretty fine. I get the idea of your logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String#sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-sub) to replace the characters step by step:

`str.sub(/\s/,'|').sub(/:/,'|').sub(/\s/,'|')`

**Tests**

```
test = [ "Usw 12:12 Desktop",
         "Usw 1:2 Netbooks",
         "Usw 1:345 Servers, mainframes and supercomputers" ]

test.map { |str| str.sub(/\s/,'|').sub(/:/,'|').sub(/\s/,'|') }                                                                      
 #=> [ "Usw|12|12|Desktop",
 #     "Usw|1|2|Netbooks",
 #     "Usw|1|345|Servers, mainframes and supercomputers" ]
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this one should be marked as correct answer, since it’s a word-to-word translation to ruby of “match first and second space and ":" from second column.”

Comment: Very different approach. I would never think in thinks way to solve it. Excellent for me to learn from your solution to think in other kind of ways to fix something. "Split and win"